# Streaming API Handshake Failure

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, streaming-api

I am always getting the following message from Streaming API workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com/streaming.php)

```
{  "channel": "/meta/handshake",   "advice": {    "reconnect": "handshake"  },   "error": "403::Server is too busy. Please try your request again later.",   "successful": false,   "id": "4",   "action": "handshake"}
```

Anyone can help me?